# Automation testing for iOS native apps on PC

Tags: ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I am looking for what seems to be improbably but I thought I'd try and ask. Does anyone know of any automated test tools for the iOS native applications that can be used on PC.

Example: I would like a Selenium FF IDE equivalent tool to run on a PC, but allow me to automate native iOS applications.

In My search so far I have come across many tools such as FoneMonkey, Froglogic, etc but all require a MAC OS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Telerik's [Test Studio For iOS](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/ios-testing/ios-application-testing.aspx)? I've messed with it a little bit. Most of my work uses Apple's UI Automation, so I've not needed it, but from what I've seen so far I'm impressed. A lot of the automation recording can happen on the device itself.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Appium](http://appium.io/) , as they said mobile automation made awesome. It use webdriver api and helps running automated test on native iOS and android environment.